# Yelp V2 API Query Loop in R

Tags: r, yelp, jsonlite

I'm using the Yelp API in R to pull down some businesses.  From what I've read in the documentation you can pull down up to 20 businesses per API call, however if you use the offset= parameter you can essentially pull down more records.

What I'm trying to do is create a simple loop to create multiple API calls with an incrementing value for the offset= parameter.

For example -- the first API call would look like this:

```
yelpURL <- paste0("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?limit=20&offset=20&sort=0&term=food&location=Chicago")
```

The next call would have the offset=20, then 40, 60, 80, and so on.  I'm not sure how to write this.  I'd like to pull down the maximum number of businesses which is 1,000 I believe and have them added to a single data frame.  Here's my full code below:

```
# yelp credentials
consumerKey = "xxxxxxx"
consumerSecret = "xxxxxxx"
token = "xxxxxxx"
tokenSecret = "xxxxxxx"

require(httr)
myApp <- oauth_app("YELP", key=consumerKey, secret=consumerSecret)
mySignature <- sign_oauth1.0(myApp, token=token, token_secret=tokenSecret)


yelpURL <- paste0("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?limit=20&offset=20&sort=0&term=food&location=Chicago")
locationData <- GET(yelpURL, mySignature)

require(jsonlite)
locationDataContent = content(locationData)
locationList=jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(locationDataContent))
results <- data.frame(locationList)
```

Answer (score 1):

A general approach for your "query loop" could be to read those urls into a list, convert each json input into a data frame and finally merge all listed data frames to a combined data frame:

```
locationDataList.raw <- lapply(sprintf("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?limit=20&offset=%d&sort=0&term=food&location=Chicago", 
                                       seq(0, 60, 20)), 
                               GET, mySignature)
locationDataList <- lapply(locationDataList.raw, function(locationData) {
  locationDataContent = content(locationData)
  locationList=jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(locationDataContent))
  return(data.frame(locationList))
})
result <- do.call(rbind, locationDataList)
```

However, to have them "added into a single data frame" you will probably have to flatten/tidy your data before merging (`rbind`). E.g. select columns of interest. But that would be another story.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like flattening up the data will be a bit of a pain.  I suppose seperate data frames would be fine.  How would you suggest I organize the results of each API call?

Comment: Tbh, I'd save `locationDataList.raw` and `locationDataList`, put the file on dropbox or sth and post a new question which references the data and asks how to `rbind` the data frames. I stumbled about similar json problems, but never found a perfect solution. However, I'm sure the pros have got one.